# How to implement AdMob native ads in Xamarin Forms IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, admob, renderer

I'm having a Xamarin Forms application where I could successfully add banner ads and native ads for the android with custom renderers using Google AdMob NuGet. What I'm trying to achieve here is to make them work on IOS, I managed to do that (I suppose as I'm receiving test ads) with banner but when it comes to native, I get unified native ad and it never renders...

I'm using it inside of a custom listview data template which I thought it might cause an issue, so I tried using it in the page itself but no luck, same issue.

Here is my IOS renderer so far:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeAdMobUnit), typeof(NativeAdMobUnitRenderer))]
namespace Example.iOS.Components
{
    public class NativeAdMobUnitRenderer : ViewRenderer<NativeAdMobUnit, NativeExpressAdView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NativeAdMobUnit> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
               
                CreateAdView(this, e.NewElement.AdUnitId);
            }
        }
        private void CreateAdView(NativeAdMobUnitRenderer renderer,String AdUnitId)
        {

            if (Element == null) return;

            var loader = new AdLoader(
               AdUnitId,
                GetVisibleViewController(),
                new AdLoaderAdType[] { AdLoaderAdType.UnifiedNative },
                new AdLoaderOptions[] {
                    new NativeAdViewAdOptions {PreferredAdChoicesPosition = AdChoicesPosition.TopRightCorner}
                });

            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
            request.TestDevices = new string[] { Request.SimulatorId };

         
            try
            {
                loader.Delegate = new MyAdLoaderDelegate(renderer);
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    loader.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest());
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
            }
        }

        private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
        {
            var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
            foreach (var window in windows)
            {
                if (window.RootViewController != null)
                {
                    return window.RootViewController;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private class MyAdLoaderDelegate : NSObject, IUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate
        {
            private readonly NativeAdMobUnitRenderer _renderer;

            public MyAdLoaderDelegate(NativeAdMobUnitRenderer renderer)
            {
                _renderer = renderer;
            }

            public void DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd(AdLoader adLoader, UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd");
            }
            public void DidFailToReceiveAd(AdLoader adLoader, RequestError error)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DidFailToReceiveAd");
            }

            public void DidFinishLoading(AdLoader adLoader)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DidFinishLoading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the same but for Android which is working as expected:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeAdMobUnit), typeof(NativeAdMobUnitRenderer))]
namespace Example.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class NativeAdMobUnitRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        public NativeAdMobUnitRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                NativeAdMobUnit NativeAdUnit = (NativeAdMobUnit)Element;
                var adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(Context, NativeAdUnit.AdUnitId);

                var listener = new UnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener();
                listener.OnNativeAdLoaded += (s, ad) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var root = new UnifiedNativeAdView(Context);
                        var inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                        var adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ad_unified, root);

                        populateUnifiedNativeAdView(ad, adView);

                        SetNativeControl(adView);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                };

                adLoader.ForUnifiedNativeAd(listener);
                var requestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                adLoader.Build().LoadAd(requestBuilder.Build());
            }
        }

        private void populateUnifiedNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd, UnifiedNativeAdView adView)
        {
            adView.MediaView = adView.FindViewById<MediaView>(Resource.Id.ad_media);

            // Set other ad assets.
            adView.HeadlineView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_headline);
            adView.BodyView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_body);
            adView.CallToActionView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_call_to_action);
            adView.IconView = adView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ad_app_icon);
            adView.PriceView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_price);
            adView.StarRatingView = adView.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ad_stars);
            adView.StoreView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_store);
            adView.AdvertiserView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_advertiser);

            // The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
            ((TextView)adView.HeadlineView).Text = nativeAd.Headline;

            // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
            // check before trying to display them.
            if (nativeAd.Body == null)
            {
                adView.BodyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.BodyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.BodyView).Text = nativeAd.Body;
            }

            if (nativeAd.CallToAction == null)
            {
                adView.CallToActionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.CallToActionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((Android.Widget.Button)adView.CallToActionView).Text = nativeAd.CallToAction;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Icon == null)
            {
                adView.IconView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                ((ImageView)adView.IconView).SetImageDrawable(nativeAd.Icon.Drawable);
                adView.IconView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nativeAd.Price))
            {
                adView.PriceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.PriceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.PriceView).Text = nativeAd.Price;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Store == null)
            {
                adView.StoreView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.StoreView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.StoreView).Text = nativeAd.Store;
            }

            if (nativeAd.StarRating == null)
            {
                adView.StarRatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((RatingBar)adView.StarRatingView).Rating = nativeAd.StarRating.FloatValue();
                adView.StarRatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Advertiser == null)
            {
                adView.AdvertiserView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((TextView)adView.AdvertiserView).Text = nativeAd.Advertiser;
                adView.AdvertiserView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            adView.SetNativeAd(nativeAd);
        }
    }

    public class UnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener : AdListener, UnifiedNativeAd.IOnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener
    {
        public void OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd ad)
        {
            OnNativeAdLoaded?.Invoke(this, ad);
        }

        public EventHandler<UnifiedNativeAd> OnNativeAdLoaded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try the code [here](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/)? Does the log print `DidFailToReceiveAd` or `DidFinishLoading`?

Comment: This code is for banner ads only... I'm here trying to implement native ads.

Comment: @MohamedAshraf did you find the solution? I'm exactly at the same situation. I can receive it via DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd but it is somehow not rendered.

Comment: @mctuna I remember I could make it work somehow at that time in the emulator but on the release it never worked, after deep investigation I found out that iOS simply does not support having ads from services not registered on Apple. There are a lot of workarounds for it but honestly I left the whole project.

Comment: @mctuna If you found a way to make it work however one way or another, you can post it in here so me and others can benefit from it and I will mark it as answered <3.

Comment: @MohamedAshraf If I make it work, I will definitely let you know.